# Laravel : Can the same files and folders be shared between projects?

Tags: laravel

Can the same files and folders be shared between projects written with laravel?

For example, there are 3 projects,they are deployed on a centos server.

And the 3 projects are similar to `stackexchange.com`,it has:

```
3dprinting.stackexchange.com
academia.stackexchange.com
android.stackexchange.com
...
...
...
etc.
```

The websites above have the same structure.

To get back to my example:

As shown in the picture below:
[image]

The databases are independent，so the `.env` files are different,
and css files,some images(such as logo) are different, they are in `public` folder.
The other files and folders are the same.

**Questions:**
Can the same files and folders be shared between projects?

And if possible,which files and folders can be shared?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, but i don't think this is a good idea.
It is not clear what do you want achieve.
But most likely the valid approach is to use [`Sub-Domain Routing`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing)
It means you can use the same files for all subdomains.

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{account}.stackexchange.com.com'], function () {
    Route::get('post/{id}', function ($account, $id) {
    });
});
```